# problem in using between function in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am developing one web application using asp.net 2005 and Microsoft SQL Server **2008**. I need a help for fetching the data from database between a given range.

the date field in my table is of type VARCHAR(25) and the date format stored is dd-mm-yyyy. when I using the between clause in the SQL query then it is not giving all the data  i.e. the date criteria in where clause is not working fine.

while my clients requirement is to keep the date format as dd-mm-yyyy and fetch the data according to the given range.

so please help me out with that what should I do in this case.

SQL query :

```
@datefrom varchar(15),  // parameter in the procedure           
@dateto varchar(15) 

set @sql = '';     
set @sql = @sql +  'SELECT * FROM ven_timesheetreportmaster vtsrm WITH (nolock)    
                    INNER JOIN ven_descriptionmaster_timesheet vdmts ON vdmts.description_id = vtsrm.description_id '  
set  @sql  = @sql +  ' WHERE vtsrm.entry_date BETWEEN ''' + @datefrom + ''' AND  ''' + @dateto  + '''  '

if ( @emp_id !='0')    
    set  @sql  = @sql +  ' AND vtsrm.emp_id =' + @emp_id + ' '
```

In the  `ven_timesheetreportmaster`  table, the `entry_date` is a `varchar` datatype..

If I pass values ,

```
@date from : 01-05-2011
@date to : 31-05-2011
```

it showing me all the values in the db from april to till date

Comment: If it's a date - why isn't it a `DATETIME` ?? Would make things just **soooo** much easier....

Comment: i am trying to change it to datetime data type now..

Comment: Also: are you using SQL Server **2008** like your title and tag indicate - or **2005** as your post says?!?!?! SQL Server **2008** introduced a number of date-related new datatypes like `DATE` (for just date - no time component) which could be helpful..

Comment: sorry it's an typo error , it is sql server 2008

Comment: What does `SELECT MONTH('01-05-2011')` return?

Comment: the output shows : 1 ; for the SELECT MONTH('01-05-2011')

Comment: hi, i tried like this,                                            (1) :ALTER TABLE [dbo].ven_timesheetreportmaster  ALTER COLUMN  updated_date datetime
            
(2):update ven_timesheetreportmaster set updated_date =CONVERT(datetime,updated_date,103).. both the above statements giving me error.. error message:  Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a string comparison on the varchar(25), not a date comparison so exactly as expected. That is, the string '06-06-2011' is before the string '31-05-2011'

Add some CONVERTs with style 112 and compare actual *dates*.

Or fix your data... the format `dd-mm-yyyy` should be set in the client code and the database should be native date/time types.

Comment: hi, i tried like this, (1) :ALTER TABLE [dbo].ven_timesheetreportmaster ALTER COLUMN updated_date datetime (2):update ven_timesheetreportmaster set updated_date =CONVERT(datetime,updated_date,103).. both the above statements giving me error.. error message: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0):

> As your query is retriving the April
>   month data
>
> so Kindly check with the inner join
>   query
>
> or just give the sample data in both
>   the Table